# How can I determine what resources an Azure application gateway backend target represents, given just an IP address?

Tags: azure, ip-address, target, azure-application-gateway

I inherited an application from someone and am trying to understand how the Azure Application
Gateway is configured.

The subscription has two backend pools in the application gateway.

Each backend pool has 3 rules and 2 targets.

My question is regarding the targets.

The targets are of type "IP address or FQDN".

Each of the targets is an IP address of 10.0.16.xx.

I don't know what those IPs represent.  How can I determine what resources the backend targets represent, knowing just the IP address?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I went to the Virtual Network (within the Azure portal), and I could see all of the devices, types, IP addresses, and subnets.  The IPs that I was looking for were there.